# RequiredFieldValidators are not showing in Order

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

In my ASP.net application using C#, I am using 4 requiredfieldvalidators. Buton Button_Click
 event, last RequiredFieldValidator is showing first as in the image.

I want to show the first RequiredFieldValidator to work first(validator for not entering the employee code)

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: Without code how we can help you ?

Comment: can you please post aspx code atleast

Answer (score 0):

`Requiredfieldvalidators` will fire in order they placed in page,change it accordingly to get your order. right.

Comment: ::: all Requiredfieldvalidators are in order